# A java.lang.NoSuchMethodException error (layouts)

Tags: java

I want to display another layout in another window, but whenever I add a new layout to start method

```
BorderPane sch = new BorderPane();
sch.setCenter(addVBox2(primaryStage));
scene1 = new Scene(sch, 800, 500);
```

I get this error

Exception in Application start method

```
Exception in thread "main" **java.lang.NoSuchMethodException**: sample.Main.main([Ljava.lang.String;)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1786)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:119)
```

Where might the problem in the code be? Thank you for any help in advance.

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {

        stage = primaryStage;

        BorderPane border = new BorderPane();
        border.setLeft(addVBox(primaryStage));
        border.setCenter(addGridPane(primaryStage));
        border.setRight(addDatePicker(primaryStage));
        HBox hbox = addHBox();
        border.setBottom(hbox);

        scene = new Scene(border, 800, 500);




        BorderPane sch = new BorderPane();
        sch.setCenter(addVBox2(primaryStage));
        scene1 = new Scene(sch, 800, 500);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Booking Form");
        stage.show(); 
}



private VBox addVBox2(Stage stage) {

    javafx.scene.control.Label label = new javafx.scene.control.Label("Choose rooms' schedule");
    label.setFont(javafx.scene.text.Font.font("Tahoma", FontWeight.BOLD, 16));
    room1 = new RadioButton("Room 1 of type 1");
    room1.setSelected(true);
    room2 = new RadioButton("Room 2 of type 1");
    room3 = new RadioButton("Room 1 of type 2");
    room4 = new RadioButton("Room 2 of type 2");
    room5 = new RadioButton("Room 1 of type 3");
    room6 = new RadioButton("Room 2 of type 3");





    VBox buttons2 = new VBox(20, label, roomtype1, roomtype2);
    buttons2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    buttons2.setMaxWidth(225);

    stackPane.getChildren().add(buttons2);

    ToggleGroup toggleGroup = new ToggleGroup();
    toggleGroup.getToggles().addAll(roomtype1, roomtype2);

    Scene scene = new Scene(stackPane, 400, 200);
    stage.setTitle("RadioButton control");

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

    return buttons2;
}


private HBox addHBox() {

    HBox hbox = new HBox();
    hbox.setPadding(new Insets(15, 12, 15, 12));
    hbox.setSpacing(10);   // Gap between nodes
    hbox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #336699;");
    hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    final Text actionTarget = new Text();



       Button schedule = new Button("Schedule");
        schedule.setPrefSize(100, 20);
        schedule.setOnAction(e -> stage.setScene(scene1));

...}
```

Comment: you have no main method main(String[])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Main.main([Ljava.lang.String;)
```

This error means your main class is not found. When you have this kind of error, most of the time it means **you moved your main class from a file to another without changing your run configuration.**

Edit your run configuration in intellij IDE. Your run configuration is pointing to wrong class it seems. [edit run configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/running-applications.html)